# Motorola Droid 2 Global SMS Issu

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am hoping someone can help.

I am writing an Android application which receive SMS through BroadcastReceiver. It is working in many Android devices but when I install it on Motorola "Droid 2 Global", it doesn't work. I have no Droid2Global device. I always test it on DeviceAnyWhere and my application's users report this issue as well.

Why Droid2Global is different and why this BroadcastReceiver is not working on this device? I am using static BroadcastReceiver.

This is my BroadcastReceiver code.

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

}
```

This is my manifest entry for this receiver.

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This is permissions for BroadcastReceiver:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set `<intent-filter android:priority="999">` so it would be notified first of all SMS Receivers